# Filtro en Thunderbird para mover mensaje a subcarpeta y marcarlo como leído

Tags: email, mensajes

El problema es muy sencillo. Necesito que un filtro mueva ciertos mensajes entrantes a una subcarpeta de la bandeja de entrada de Thunderbird e inmediatamente marque estos como leídos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi primer filtro de la lista. Y mueve correctamente los mensajes, pero no quedan marcados como leídos.

No quiero marcar como leídos todos los mensajes de la subcarpeta, únicamente los que han sido movidos por este filtro.

¿Es posible conseguir esto?

-- ThunderbirdPortable versión 60.3.3 (32-bit) (windows) --

Answer (score 1):

No hay que hacer nada especial, basta con poner el filtro que te interese (en mi caso buscar un texto en el asunto) y después en `Realizar estas acciones`, primero `Mover a carpeta` y después `Marcar como leído`, en ese orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probado en versión 52.9.1 (64-bit) (linux)

(edito)

Actualizado a la versión 60.2.1 (64-bit) y funciona igual.

Comment: Así es como lo tengo, pero no funciona. La diferencia contigo puede que sea que mi subcarpeta de destino está creada dentro de la bandeja de entrada. Según indica, TB primero marca como leído y luego mueve el mensaje. Al aparecer el mensaje por primera vez en una subcarpeta de la de entrada la política de TB creo que lo marca automáticamente de nuevo como no leído. Puede que este sea el problema. Lo que ignoro es la solución.

Comment: @Jorgeska, yo también tengo la subcarpeta de destino dentro de la bandeja de entrada (aunque si eso te genera duda prueba a cambiarla). Actualizado a la versión 60.2.1 (64-bit) y sigue igual.

Comment: Mismo comportamiento cambiando el destino por ejemplo a la papelera. ¿Puede que sea un bug de esta versión 60.3.3? No he indicado que utilizo la versión Portable, aunque no creo que tenga importancia.

Comment: @Jorgeska ¿seguro que no hay más reglas que interfieran?

Comment: Añado captura en la consulta. He probado sin éxito a cambiar en el filtro "De" x "Asunto" y a quitar "Detener ejecución de más filtros", ... para que sea exactamente como en tu ejemplo. He puesto el filtro el primero de la lista. Mismo resultado @Fly.

Comment: @Jorgeska ¿Como tienes configurada la cuenta? ¿pop o imap? yo en esta cuenta uso pop

Comment: es una cuenta Exchange, configurada a través de ExQuilla.